# Is there a way to invoke pdb on those pytests that failed last time

Tags: python, testing, pytest

`pytest --lf --pdb` does not quite do what I want because it starts the debugger after the function I'm testing has already produced the incorrect behavior.

For example, suppose that I have a file called `test_project.py` that contains the following:

```
def test_plus_one():
    v = plus_one(9)
    assert v == 10
```

After running `pytest`, I notice that this test is failing because `plus_one(9)` returned `11` instead of `10`, so I run `pytest --lf --pdb`.  However, this invokes pdb after the assert statement has already failed.  What I would really like to do is to invoke pdb on the preceeding line `v = plus_one(9)` so as to step into the call to the function `plus_one`.

I know that I could just call `pdb.set_trace()` inside `plus_one`, but is there a more convenient way (perhaps some combination of flags to pytest)?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about flags to pytest but you can stick an `assert False` above the call to `plus_one` and get pytest to halt there and drop you into the debugger.

Even better is to extract the code which can produce the error out into a small driver program and `pdb` that directly.